# Paypal sandbox payment succeeded but not showing in sandbox summary

Tags: wordpress, paypal

Hello Everyone i am using pay-pal sandbox for pay-pal express checkout. I am getting success and  my payment Id, token id and payer Id also generated. But when I am going to sandbox summary, its not showing under my payment transactions.
Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong? If payment got succeeded then why its not showing in summary area.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using REST API and you have successfully "Create Payment".

You will need to fully run "Execute Payment" to complete the transaction. You can refer here for more information:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_execute